# Apache Logging - Send log output directly to queue

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, activemq-classic

Am using Standard apache logging (`org.apache.log4j.logging` )

Currently, taking the data to be logged manually, and publishing in to Apache Active MQ.

Is it possible to configure the logging output to publish directly in to Active MQ??
This might sound stupid, but since both are from Apache, I have a doubt that whether, it has any implicit support, which I could not grab it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

log4j provides [JMSAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.html) out of the box. It allows publishing logging events to JMS Topic.

For configuration specific to ActiveMQ please check the documentation - [How do I use log4j JMS appender with ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you were looking for log4j-1.x or log4j-2.0, but here are the links for log4j-2.0:

- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JMSQueueAppender
- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JMSTopicAppender